# A query in a step when deriving Maxwell's equations from stationary action

Tags: electromagnetism, field-theory, tensor-calculus, variational-calculus

When varying the Maxwell action, one gets to the following part

$$
\begin{align}
\delta \left(F^{\mu \nu} F_{\mu \nu}\right) &= 2 F^{\mu \nu} \delta F_{\mu \nu} \\
&= 2 F^{\mu \nu} \left(\partial_\mu \delta A_\nu - \partial_\nu \delta A_\mu\right) \\
&= 4 F^{\mu \nu} \partial_\mu \delta A_\nu
\end{align}
$$

However, how does one actually get from the second last step to the last step? I tried to write out the indices and I got double of the term in the second last step (without the factor of 2) instead.

Comment: $F^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\delta A_{\mu}=-F^{\nu\mu}\partial_{\nu}\delta A_{\mu}=-F^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}\delta A_{\nu}$, since $\mu$ and $\nu$ indices are dummy. Hence the two terms add in 2nd last step and we get the last step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are dummy summation indices in $F^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\nu}\delta A_{\mu}$. Make the change $ \mu \rightarrow \nu$ and $\nu \rightarrow \mu$. You will get $F^{\nu\mu}\partial_{\mu}\delta A_{\nu}$. And now simply use the antisymmetry of the Faraday field tensor to get rid of the minus sign.